# The title bar is a bit misaligned

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

The title bar is a bit misaligned,

It's not much, but it makes it hard for my OCD.

> [image]

On the other sites, it's not a problem :

> [image]

Comment: Are you sure you have OCD and not just OCPD?

Comment: @random I'm waiting for my test results..

Comment: This is true for every theme across the SE network. At least on every site I've ever visited the Ask Question page.

Comment: So do small errrs bother you?

Comment: @animuson You never posted on stack overflow? (view edit of the post)

Comment: It is misaligned for me on Stack Overflow. But I'm also using custom CSS there so that may be it. But I just checked Gaming and The Workplace and it is misaligned. Oddly though English SE doesn't appear misaligned for me.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/DjuBr.jpg

Comment: If we're going to fix that, we may as well fix it all the way down...the tags bar isn't aligned either (with the title bar OR the body container).

Comment: @Laura Let's fix it all the way then.